# Installing grails plugins in a runtime

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm working on a modular grails application and I'm interested in registering / installing grails plugins during a runtime, preferably without having to restart the application. Is it technically possible? How it can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While it might be possible to hack the plugin system completely apart and make this work in some fashion it's not really feasible.

Given the way plugins within a Grails application are installed ([documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html)) and that the entire plugin system is designed to be used at build time I would advise against even attempting this.

If you are looking for a modular approach to installing and removing portions of your application at runtime you might be better off looking into [OSGI](http://www.osgi.org/Main/HomePage).

Comment: I'm actually successfully using OSGi in my application, but I want to be able not only supply some code to grails, but to register it as grails plugins or other grails artefacts.

Comment: Put simply, adding Grails plugins or Grails artifacts at runtime can not be done. The plugin and artifact system is designed to be used a build time, not runtime.